# Shortcut from Recent Applications always launch latest activity of application. How to change that?

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to launch always a specific activity, not this which was active during closing application. I don't have possibility switching to desirable activity before closing, because it could be dead.

I would prefer even delete shortcut to whole program from recent app than make user confused by launch credits instead of start splash screen. However this would be only workaround (but just in case, how can I do that?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to start your application through the same activity every time, add

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

to your main activity in the manifest file. This will force your application to put this activity at the bottom of the activity stack clearing all other activities which may have been running.

Comment: This is wrong. Adding this special launch mode to the main `Activity` will not achieve the OP's goal. It will not clear other activities from the stack. I have no idea how this got accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I decompiled some apps and found their solution:

```
    <android:name="..."
        android:taskAffinity=":shortcut"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        ...
```

About [android:taskAffinity](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#aff):

> An affinity name that applies to all activities within the application, except for those that set a different affinity with their own taskAffinity attributes. See that attribute for more information.
>
> By default, all activities within an application share the same affinity. The name of that affinity is the same as the package name set by the `<manifest>` element.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can achieve this would be to mark all your activities with [`android:excludeFromRecents="true"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude) attribute. this would ensure that none of your activities shows in the Recent Applications list.

You should also look into the [`android:finishOnTaskLaunch`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#finish) and [`android:stateNotNeeded`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#state) attributes.

Comment: If you mark your main `Activity` with `excludeFromRecents="true"`, then the user would not find the task in the list of recent tasks and would be unable to return to the task if he left it (by pressing the HOME button or answering an incoming phone call, etc.). There is no need to mark **all** activities with this attribute, only the main (root) `Activity` is enough.

Comment: This answer will prevent the application from ever showing up in the list of recent tasks. That may not be what OP wants. Not only that, but if the app has 2 activities open and the user presses the HOME button, then returns to the app (not by selecting it from the list of recent tasks, but by pressing the application's icon on the HOME screen again) then it will return to the app with the second `Activity` on top, which is also not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to solve this is to add

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

to the manifest entry for all activities **except for the main (root) `Activity`**.

When the user returns to your application, either from the list of recent tasks or by pressing the app icon on the HOME page, all activities (except for the main (root) `Activity`) will be removed from the task (actually, they get removed immediately when the user navigates away from the app by pressing the HOME button, answering an incoming phone call, choosing another app from the Notification bar, etc.